# Make Div fill full width but with sidebar - Not dependant on content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Ok, Im not even sure if this is possible but here goes my question.

I have two divs, `<div id="article">` and `<div id="sidebar">` And I would like them in a two column responsive layout. However the #sidebar I would like to stay a fixed width.

Currently I have the following setup:

```
<html>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="article">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

-

```
#article {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 300px 0 0;
}

#sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -300px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This basically works, However the #article div does not always fill the space if there is not enough content in it. Is there a way to fill the div with content to make it expand to its full width? I wanted a horizontal ruler to go across the full page, but its only going the width of the longest heading I have.

Primitive example: http://imgur.com/Z7qwcNk

Comment: Is it possible to use jquery?

Comment: I prefer to use html and css only if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/ug2dA/)**

css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#container {
    height: 100%; /* to occupy full width and height */
    width: 100%;
}
#article {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 300px); /* will adjust the width of sidebar */
    float: left;
    background: green;
}
#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="article">
         <h1>Hello World tes test test test test tes tete test test tes testve</h1>

    </div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the calc() css3? and do I have to do anything special for older browsers? Im surprised I never saw this before!

Comment: More about calc here : http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/ and browser support is IE9 and above, chrome 19 and above, mozilla supports it. As of today all modern browser supports it. For older browser you can also use prefixes like -webkit-calc(), -moz-calc()

Comment: Thanks!! This worked wonderfully. The trick I learned was that the whitespace on either side of the + and - is very necessary

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/575Lp/).  It won't get you a fixed width, but it will get you a proportional width.  I think that's going to be your best bet while still keeping it responsive.  You could also use width: calc(100% - *your fixed pixel width*).  However, that will not work in ie8 and below if you need to support that browser.

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
   background-color: yellow;
   overflow:hidden;
    height: 700px;
 }

 #article {
   width: 70%;
   display:inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
 }

 #sidebar {
    background-color: blue;
   float: right;
   width: 30%;
 }
```